# Splice matching function arguments

Tags: functions, core-language, sequence

Mathematica 12.1 introduces `Splice` that replaces the old way of using `Sequence@@` to "melt" a list of entries. However, the argument matching seems to be not working as intended.

Suppose we have `data = {a, b}` and the following polymorphic function definitions:

```
data = {a, b};

f[x_] = 1;
f[x_, y_] = 2;
```

Using `Sequence@@` would result in the following:

```
f[Sequence @@ data]
(* 2 *)
```

But if we use `Splice`

```
f[Splice[data]]
(* 1 *)
```

Is this intentional or a Bug? If this is intentional, could anyone explain why such behavior is favored over the `Sequence @@` method?

Comment: Using `Sequence[]` is of course the more general approach. But it is because of this generality that one might want things to only work in e.g. lists, and that's where `Splice[]` comes in.

Comment: @J.M. Thank your for your explanation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html?q=Splice) say that

> `Splice[{e1,e2,…}]` is equivalent to `Sequence[e1,e2,…]` when the outer wrapping head is `List`.

In your example the outer wrapping head is `f`.  In the [`Basic Examples`](https://wolfram.com/xid/0y7y02-ioybrz) section it gives one instance,

> `head[a, b, c, Splice[{1, 2, 3}], d, e]`

which returns with the `Splice` unevaluated.  So your `f` sees *one* argument, `Splice[{a,b}]`, and returns 1 according to its definition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!